# Изменение цвета при наведении

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Мне нужно сделать js, чтобы когда наводите мышь на фотографию, менялся цвет бордюра (а когда покидаете фотографию, возвращался обратно цвет, который был). Я это успешно сделал:

```
$('.logo_js').hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        "border-color": "#FF80FF"
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).css({
        "border-color": "#DFDFDF"
    });
});
```

Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии пользователем на фотографию цвет становился зелёным. У меня это не работает, так как при потере фокуса цвет возвращается на #DFDFDF.

Как сделать так, чтобы цвета менялись при наведении, а при нажатии цвет бордюра становился зелёным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.logo_js').hover(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) return;
    $(this).css({
        "border-color": "#FF80FF"
    });
}, function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) return;
    $(this).css({
        "border-color": "#DFDFDF"
    });
});
$('.logo_js').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
// css: .logo_js.clicked { border-color: #00ff00; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Гуглим CSS, в особенности `a:hover`, `a:active` и `a:visited`.

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

> css тут не нужен!

Я бы сказал, что js тут не нужен. ;) Ок, вот еще вариант.

html:

```
<a class="someclass clickOnce"></a>
```

css:

```
.someclass{border-color:green}
.someclass:hover, .clickOnce:hover{border-color:red}
.clickOnce{border-color:blue}
```

js:

```
$('.clickOnce').live('click', function(){$(this).removeClass('clickOnce');});
```

Comment: css тут не нужен!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.logo_js').click(function () {
    $(this).css({
        "border-color": "#зеленый"
    });
    }
```

может так?

но нужно проверять чтобы после нажатия, не срабатывал hover

Ну при клике на фотку можно добавить ей класс, допустим **"hoveroff"** тогда при

```
$('.logo_js').hover(function () {
```

Проверять есть ли у **logo_js** стиль **hoveroff**, если есть то ничего не делать, а если нет то делать. собственно убрать этот стиль повторным нажатием на фотку.

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы после нажатия не срабатывал hover

Comment: обновил ответ